# configure gitlab to build the source code on another machine

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We have two servers in our organisation.
1) server with gitlab 
2) Build server

I would like to create an automate build happen in the second machine(Build server ) for the source code in the gitlab server.

How can I achieve this using gitlab ?

Thanks,
siva

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving from an "pull" continuous integration system (e.g. using a kind of crontab that regularly checks if the source code on the versioning system has changed and start the configure/build/test/deploy stages if it has), then know that gitlab has a much better way of doing this.

gitlab approach is to configure a "pull" system: every time the code is updated (in any branch) on the git repository then the script defined in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` is read to see if continuous integration jobs have to be launched. jobs are send to your configured gitlab runners. gitlab runners are defined on your build server(s) and takes the job when they are coming.
Definition of what to do is also describes in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Here is a list of documentation to start learning about gitlab CI:

- [the official documentation can be helpful](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/README.html)
- A general introduction to gitlab ci using docker can be found [in this blog article](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/02/05/test-all-the-things-gitlab-ci-docker-examples/) (the first slides are great). If your build server or your intended build is on Linux,  I would recommend using the "docker executor" (e.g. gitlab runners are executed inside a docker machine inside your build server). It is easy and quick to setup.

Hope this helps you starting...